# Pushing to +master versus force push

Tags: git, github

When I resynchronize with an upstream project on GitHub that I've forked, I thought I needed to force push. However, pushing to `+master` also seems to work.

What's the difference between:

```
git push origin +master
```

and

```
git push --force origin master
```

?

Is one less dangerous than the other?

Comment: `git push --force` is extremely dangerous. In fact using `-f` or `--force` on any command in git that accepts it is usually dangerous.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante `git push --force` is only dangerous if you don't know what you are doing.  So long as the branch you are pushing is not shared by anyone else, there is nothing inherently wrong with it.  Whether @StevenShaw should be using `push --force` is a different question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Sure - the first part of my comment was implicitly prefaced with "On shared repositories, ". Of course there is little chance of overwriting your own changes on a branch unless you have several separate copies of it.

Comment: Forced pushes are about as dangerous as crossing the street.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> Note that --force applies to all the refs that are pushed, hence using it with push.default set to matching or with multiple push destinations configured with remote.*.push may overwrite refs other than the current branch (including local refs that are strictly behind their remote counterpart). To force a push to only one branch, use a + in front of the refspec to push

`git push origin +master` and `git push --force origin master` both will do the **same** thing, since in the latter case you specify only one ref.

Nothing which Git created is inherently evil, and doing a Git force push is appropriate when you want to overwrite a remote branch.  One example when you would want to do this is after rebasing a personal feature branch on some other branch and then pushing it out to a repository.

Answer (score 1):

The `+master` syntax is equivalent to using `--force`, but it's more flexible. For example, you can write

```
git push origin master +pu
```

if you want to force-push branch `pu` and push `master` without forcing the push.

Both versions are equivalently dangerous if you don't know what you are doing.

`--force` may be dangerous if you're not specifying which branch to push and if you're unsure about how `push.default` is configured. For example

```
git push --force
```

may rewind a branch which is not the current one if you have `push.default=matching` (this was one of the motivation for changing the default value for `push.default` to `simple`). For example, if you are currently on a branch `dev` that you want to force-push and you also have a branch `master` not up-to-date with upstream, then with `push.default=matching`, a `git push --force` would rewind `master` as well as update your `dev` branch.